# A topology question from Dugundji

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space having a basis of connected open sets. Let $U$ be a component of open subspace $G$ of $X$. Why is $G$ intersection $\text{Fr}(U) = \phi$, $\text{Fr}(U)= \text{Cl}(U)-\text{Int}(U)$

It's a question of Topology Dugundji. I know the space whose base is connected open sets is locally connected and a component whose subspace is open is also open.  But how to start this question and what to do to prove this.

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Answer (score 0):

Components of a locally connected space are clopen.
Thus their boundaries (frontiers) are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be a base (basis) for $X$ consisting of connected open sets.

For any component $U$ of $G$ and any $x\in U,$ since $G$ is open in $X$ there exists $V_x\in B$ with $x\in V_x\subset G.$ And since $V_x$ is connected, therefore $V_x\subset U.$

Hence $U$ is open in $X.$ Hence $Fr_X(U)=Cl_X(U)\setminus U.$

Suppose there existed $p\in G\cap Fr_X(U).$ Then $p\in G\setminus U$ so $p\in U^*$ for some component $U^*$ of $G$ with $U^*\ne U.$ More sharply, $U^*\cap U=\phi.$

But $U^*$ is an open subset of $X$ that contains $p,$ and  $p\in Cl_X(U)$ so we must have $U^*\cap U\ne \phi.$ Contradiction.